# Print All JSON Results if Key Value Equals True

Tags: json, python-3.x, urllib

I know this is probably a simple question but I'm a noob and I have spent 3 days searching for the answer to my question with no luck.

Here is a sample of the JSON results I want to search through. I only want to print the JSON results if the key "IsFree" = true.

```
[
{
"InventorySliceId": 20946771,
"InventoryDateId": 8050,
"StartTime": "2020-10-16T00:00:00",
"UnitId": 5096,
"UnitTypeId": 4303,
"IsPremium": false,
"IsFree": false,
"IsBlocked": false,
"IsReserved": true,
"IsWalkin": false,
"ReservationId": 2651378,
"FacilityId": 377,
"LockExpiration": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"IsLocked": false
 },
```

Honestly I have tried 50 different samples of code and everytime I got errors about the data needs to be an int etc. Here is the current code I put together and it prints nothing.

```
import json
import urllib.request

# download raw json object
url = 
"https://calirdr.usedirect.com/rdr/rdr/fd/availability
/getbyunit/5096/startdate/2020-10-16/nights/5/true? "

data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()

# parse json object
obj = json.loads(data)

for i in obj:
if i['IsFree'] == 'false':
    print(json.dumps(obj, indent=1))
```

Comment: _"Honestly I have tried 50 different samples of code and everytime I got errors"_: this indicates that you aren't _reading the errors_ or are trying to code by trial and error. The error usually tells you _exactly_ what's wrong. Troubleshooting errors is an absolutely crucial skill for a programmer. Please correctly [format](/help/formatting) the code in your question, and [edit] it to include the json file and error message. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine, if you fix the indentation of your last `for i in obj:` block, and if you change `== 'false'` to `== False`. `json.loads()` converts the `"IsFree": "false"` in your json string to `["IsFree"] = False` in your python dict, so you just need to do `if i['IsFree'] == False:`, or even more concise, `if not i['IsFree']:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using request's built in json response, which translate it to a valid python dict (or in your case, list of dicts)

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
resp = requests.get("https://calirdr.usedirect.com/rdr/rdr/fd/availability/getbyunit/5096/startdate/2020-10-16/nights/5/true?")
for res in resp.json():
    if res['IsFree'] is False:
        pprint(res)
```

Result:

```
[{'InventorySliceId': 20946771,
  'InventoryDateId': 8050,
  'StartTime': '2020-10-16T00:00:00',
  'UnitId': 5096,
  'UnitTypeId': 4303,
  'IsPremium': False,
  'IsFree': False,
  'IsBlocked': False,
  'IsReserved': True,
  'IsWalkin': False,
  'ReservationId': 2651378,
  'FacilityId': 377,
  'LockExpiration': '0001-01-01T00:00:00',
  'IsLocked': False},
 {'InventorySliceId': 20946968,
  'InventoryDateId': 8049,
  'StartTime': '2020-10-17T00:00:00',
  'UnitId': 5096,
  'UnitTypeId': 4303,
  'IsPremium': False,
  'IsFree': False,
  'IsBlocked': False,
  'IsReserved': True,
  'IsWalkin': False,
  'ReservationId': 2651378,
  'FacilityId': 377,
  'LockExpiration': '0001-01-01T00:00:00',
  'IsLocked': False},
 {'InventorySliceId': 20947072,
  'InventoryDateId': 8052,
  'StartTime': '2020-10-18T00:00:00',
  'UnitId': 5096,
  'UnitTypeId': 4303,
  'IsPremium': False,
  'IsFree': False,
  'IsBlocked': False,
  'IsReserved': True,
  'IsWalkin': False,
  'ReservationId': 2583386,
  'FacilityId': 377,
  'LockExpiration': '0001-01-01T00:00:00',
  'IsLocked': False},
 {'InventorySliceId': 20947253,
  'InventoryDateId': 8051,
  'StartTime': '2020-10-19T00:00:00',
  'UnitId': 5096,
  'UnitTypeId': 4303,
  'IsPremium': False,
  'IsFree': False,
  'IsBlocked': False,
  'IsReserved': True,
  'IsWalkin': False,
  'ReservationId': 2583386,
  'FacilityId': 377,
  'LockExpiration': '0001-01-01T00:00:00',
  'IsLocked': False},
 {'InventorySliceId': 20947341,
  'InventoryDateId': 8053,
  'StartTime': '2020-10-20T00:00:00',
  'UnitId': 5096,
  'UnitTypeId': 4303,
  'IsPremium': False,
  'IsFree': False,
  'IsBlocked': False,
  'IsReserved': True,
  'IsWalkin': False,
  'ReservationId': 2527842,
  'FacilityId': 377,
  'LockExpiration': '0001-01-01T00:00:00',
  'IsLocked': False}]
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help I really appreciate it. This website is awesome!

Answer (score -1):

for this you have to change code

```
obj = json.loads(data)

for i in obj: if i['IsFree'] == 'false': print(json.dumps(obj, indent=1))`
```

to

```
for i in obj: if i[0].IsFree == 'false':print(json.dumps(obj, indent=1))
```

It should work fine

Comment: This answer is _wrong!_ Once OP loads `obj = json.loads(data)`, iterating over `i in obj` removes the need to do `i[0]`. Also, `i[0].IsFree` _wouldn't work!_ That's not how you access dictionary elements. And finally, `== 'false'` is wrong too. `json.loads` parses the `'false'` into boolean `False` values. ***Everything that could be wrong with this answer is wrong.***